# Decoding the Playfair cipher with a crib

Tags: playfair

I have a Playfair cipher text and I know a portion of the text (one world). How can I decode the cipher from here? Thanks.

Comment: This is, IMO, a perfect example of [a useful duplicate question](/help/duplicates); the linked question does provide the answer, but there's no way you'd guess that from the title. Upvoted and voted to close. :)